# How do I listen for network traffic on an interface/device using Java?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, qos

I'm looking to implement a reverse QoS system (because I don't have the resources to saturate my network to actually do QoS). Everything I have seen about capturing network traffic using Java seems to point to [Jpcap](https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap) - a 3+ year old library, or to other similar projects. Additionally, reading through the [java.net](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) documentation didn't help much, though the ServerSocket class seems to be on the right track.

What I'm looking for is the actual library source code, or a newer/supported framework for this. I want to grab all packets coming over the network and throw them into buffers, and then release them from the buffers after a designated amount of time, depending on the protocol the packet is carrying.

I know how to create socket applications, but have no idea how to go a level up (down technically) to interfaces. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is simply outside of the scope for a universal java application.

If you're planning on keeping a specific OS in mind, such as Windows or Linux (my following examples), then there are a few things you can do.

For Windows, any given application will be unable to do this without driver privileges. WinPCap is probably the most widely used tool in this case, and that's what jpcap utilizes. It's a "driver" that basically just Man-in-the-middle's your traffic.

For Linux, take a look at this other post https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13267/monitoring-outgoing-network-traffic

I know this is a sideways answer since it gives no Java code, but that's because Java simply isn't built to interface with the system in that way.

Comment: So your suggesting I first capture some data with a traditional program and then read it in to the Java program to simulate a network? I'm alright doing this in C/C++ too if that opens up any more options.

Comment: That would greatly increase your options, especially on a Linux platform. For Windows, though, take a look at using Winpcap with C++, and you can do it in real-time instead of waiting for the traffic to be dumped.